# Swift animations in a new view happen instantly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

One my primary view, animations execute according to the delay and durations set. However, when I segue to a new view, the animations are all complete instantly. How is this? This only happens when this animations told to execute from code in the viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setProgress()
}

// the function below annimates a circular progress view

func setProgress() {
    var to:Double = ((360.0 / 4) * increment)
    progressCircle.animateFromAngle(360.0, toAngle: to, duration: 5) { completed in
        if completed {
            print("animation stopped, completed")
        } else {
            print("animation stopped, was interrupted")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` occurs before the view is presented on screen, if you want to run animations you should probably run them in `viewDidAppear` so that the view is loaded on screen and the components are visible.

Answer (score 0):

call setProgress() in viewDiDAppear

```
override public func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setProgress()  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add delay and keep it running on a timer after viewdidload event of controller. Therefore you may reach your goal and run the animations in the time that you want.